# Cannot return the values in the list

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to return the final value of the list which is new_list[3] but it return nothing at the end. I can get the final value of new_list[3] by using print function. I am quite confusing about the return function. Is it possible it return new_list[times] when the 2 for loop is ended?

```
original_list = [100,300,400,900,1500]

def filter_list(_list,times):

    L = len(_list)
    new_list = [list(_list) for k in range(times+1)]
    for k in range (0,times):
        for j in range (0,L):
            if j == 0: #exclude the term [j-1] because new_list[-1] is not exist
                new_list[k+1][j] = int(new_list[k][j]*0.2 + new_list[k][j+1]*0.5)
            elif j == L-1: #exclude the term [j+1] because new_list[L] is not exist
                new_list[k+1][j] = int(new_list[k][j-1]*0.4 + new_list[k][j]*0.2)
            else:
                new_list[k+1][j] = int(new_list[k][j-1]*0.4 + new_list[k][j]*0.2 + new_list[k][j+1]*0.5)
    return (new_list[times])

filter_list(original_list,3)
```

Comment: I am getting `[263, 561, 744, 763, 436]`.

Comment: Did you `print(filter_list(original_list,3))` to see result?

Comment: @Austin I am using jupyter notebook, the last line is automatically printed!

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti OP might not be using a Jupyter notebook. ;)

Comment: @Austin I thought he is having a problem with the function itself rather than, missing printing the output.!!

Answer (score 1):

A function is able to "return" a value back to the scope that called it. If this variable is not stored or passed into another function, it is lost.

For instance:

def f(x):
       return x + 1
   f(5)

will not print anything since nothing is done with the `6` returned from the `f(5)` call.

To output the value returned from a function, we can pass it to the `print()` function:

```
print(f(5))
```

or in your case:

```
print(filter_list(original_list, 3))
```

Comment: Is it any other way to do it without using print but only return? Because this is part of my assignment which only allow me to use return function.

Comment: @Shen If you want an output, you must use print simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the return function does:

A return statement ends the execution of the function call and "returns" the result, i.e. the value of the expression following the return keyword, to the caller. If the return statement is without an expression, the special value None is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the item but not assigning it to anything

```
x = filter_list(original_list,3)

print(x)
```

What this will do is assign whatever you return from your function call to a variable in this case `x` and then your variable will hold whatever you returned so now

Heres a simple model to visualize this

```
def something():
    x = 1
    return x

def something_print():
    x = 1
    return print(x)

a = something()
print(a)

something_print()
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 fucntion_call.py 
> 1
> 1
> ```